# Android where native code was stored?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory, dalvik

We all know that Android objects and local variables are stored in the Dalvik-heap and stack.
When we execute native functions from an Android application, it creates objects and local variables.

So the **question is** **where** are **native objects** and **local variables** stored?

Answer (score 1):

Every Dalvik thread has a native part, created by the pthreads library, and a managed part, created by the VM runtime.  When you execute native code, it executes on the native stack.  (My understanding is that this changes in Art, which has a combined stack for native and managed code.)

Any allocations made by native code through `malloc()` or `new` will use the same native heap that other native code -- including the VM runtime itself -- uses.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know native code runs on native heap so they dont occupy any memory from the allocated heap.